# No internet connection via LAN or Wifi

Tags: drivers, network-interface, networkmanager, internet

**first time** installing Kali Linux, so to be fair I **don´t have much knowledge of Linux**.

During installation of Kali Linux my **network card was not recognized** by the setup and following to that, the **required drivers were not installed** in the process.

I can connect my Laptop to the internet via an Ethernet to USB adapter. The **LAN connection is recognized**, but I still have **no internet**. Neither is my wifi working, which was the reason I switched to LAN.

I got the **realtek rtl8852ae wifi 6 802.11ax pcie adapter** if that helps

**Please help me, I dont wanna give up so early!**

P.S. I can run any command in the console to diagnose the problem!

Comment: to clarify, when you connected via Ethernet you have internet connection? What Ethernet to USB adapter did you use?

Comment: don't bother with Kali ... it is not meant for general use ... get a user friendly linux distribution like Mint or Ubuntu

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). After you have read that, reconsider your choices.

Answer (score 0):

The driver for the Realtek RTL8852AE is rtw89, which is included in the mainline Linux kernel as of 5.16, released in January 2022. Kali Linux is based on Debian, so it most likely has an older kernel, but you have a few options here.

1. Compile the driver for your kernel:
   If you would like to compile the driver for your kernel, you can visit [this github page](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89) which has the code and complete instructions on how to do so.
2. Install the 5.16 kernel: The 5.16 kernel is not officially supported by Debian or Kali as of , but you may be able to install it from an "unstable" or "experimental" branch. Otherwise, you can compile it yourself.

Of course, neither of these things will be possible to do with no network connection, so if your USB to Ethernet dongle isn't giving you an internet connection, you will need another device with a connection in order to do some of these steps.

Additionally, you can *and most likely should* install a beginner-friendly distribution, on which your USB to Ethernet adapter will almost certainly work. You will likely still have to install a newer kernel or compile the drivers, since they aren't included by default, but everything else will likely be working.